# md-autocomplete md-clear-button="true" does not show the clear button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I have the issue with [`<md-autocomplete>`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) component which is shown in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dma_k/j9afow1L/3/):

`<md-autocomplete md-clear-button="true">` does not work. I would expect that a cross is shown at the end of the input field, like it is shown for official [Basic Usage demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete).

If someone can update the my demo so that clear button works, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually works fine in current version `v1.1.4` (perhaps above v1.1.2). See [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/2qtakpcr/).

Also, it seems this was intentional behavior while using `md-floating-label` for `md-autocomplete` according to some GitHub issues ([#2727](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2727) and [#7800](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7800))

If you don't have a choice of updating the `angular-material` version, you can have a look at [this comment](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2727#issuecomment-216231082) which turns out to be a somewhat applauded work-around.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for effort. Maybe you have noticed in my demo that I tried to add top padding for all input fields with one CSS rule, however it makes `md-autocomplete` to incorrectly calculate the position of cross and also drop-down list. Do you think this is a bug or can it be relatively easy workarounded with CSS?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdbpYv?editors=1010 ..md-autocomplete reset is not working

Answer (score 1):

Update your `angularjs-material` version to 1.1.2 and above. Just compare versions [1.1.0 (under the attributes section)](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) and [1.1.2 (there's a dedicative section for `md-clear-button` attribute)](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/api/directive/mdAutocomplete#clear-button-for-the-input)

<del>**NOTE:** Looks like Google hasn't served `angularjs-material` for versions 1.1.2 and above. Use [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-material) instead.</del>

**UPDATE**: Google now serves `angularjs-material` for versions 1.1.2 and above. [More info](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#angular-material)

Here's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9afow1L/8/).

Comment: Thanks for noticing that! Perhaps that was the reason why I haven't pick up the latest version of the library: I couldn't locate it on Google site.

Comment: @dma_k Looks like Google now serves versions 1.1.2 and above!

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdbpYv?editors=1010 ..md-autocomplete reset is not working